# How can I duplicate a remote Linux machine as closely as reasonably possible?

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, debian, raspberry-pi2

I have a client running an application of ours on a Raspberry Pi in PA.  I want to replicate, as closely as possible, their system to a spare Pi here I have at the office.  Mostly I want to do this so that I can, with near 100% surety, know that new software I put on their system will run without problems. The link between here and there is not bad, and I've read somewhere about using rcp to do a backup like this, but how long that will take is anyone's guess.

The system is a Raspberry Pi2 running "Raspbian", or Debian Wheezy.

This is their current "uname -a".

```
Linux pa0036 3.18.11-v7+ #781 SMP PREEMPT Tue Apr 21 18:07:59 BST 2015 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

I guess a secondary question is: can I update their machine without having to reboot?  I can reboot that system but keep in mind that I'm in TN and they are in PA, so a hardwired connection is not possible.

If there is a secondary mechanism, where I can build an inventory of their system and then force that installation to my parse pi, that is an option too.  I'm open to any suggestions, really.

Answer (score 0):

You could install exactly the same Raspbian on both sides. If you keep
them updated you should have identical systems. This is what I do. A
reboot (on either side) should only be needed if you do an

```
apt-get dist-upgrade
```

and it actually results in the kernel being
upgraded. Of course, any running processes will continue to run the
old versions of the software until restarted.

For any non-system files and directories I use *rsync*. It is
efficient, flexible (lots of options) and works nicely over *ssh*.